# How can I hide an li containing text that starts with a dash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Chosen library. I have a long hierarchy select drop down list of parent and child items. It is automatically populated. I want to hide all li's containing text that starts with a dash character, example -General Discussion. I would also like to scope the hiding to only inside of the ul class name chosen-results.

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
  //Below is the li of a child (I want to hide this li)
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">-General 
  Discussion</li>
  //Below is the li of a parent ( I want to leave this alone)
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">Accident Prevention 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Updated. This works on node preview mode, but not in node edit mode

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.chosen-results li").each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().charAt(0) === '-') {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Below I tried to use .ajaxComplete, but it does not work.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("ul.chosen-results li").each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().charAt(0) === '-') {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript/jQuery to hide the li elements with the text starting with a dash character. Here is a sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.chosen-results li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().charAt(0) === '-') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

This code will run when the document is ready and select all li elements inside the ul with the class chosen-results. It will then loop through each li element and check if the first character of its text is a dash. If it is, the li element will be hidden.

Comment: thanks you, this works on a static html page. But I am using the Drupal and the Chosen library https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen. So in node edit mode there is a select drop down list and this is using Chosen. I tried using .ajaxComplete, but it did not work.

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: This seems to be a Drupal problem. The JS is loading in node-edit mode on the admin theme, but it still does not work. I will post on drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery.

- use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) on the LI's `textContent` to remove wrapping whitespaces
- use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to match `^-` (starts with dash)
- or use [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
- or use *index* `String[i]` to match a single character at String index
- use [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to toggle a specific CSS utility class (to hide the element using i.e: `display: none;`)

#### Using [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".chosen-results li").forEach((li) => {
  li.classList.toggle("u-hidden", /^-/.test(li.textContent.trim()));
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */
.u-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">
    -General Discussion
  </li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">
    Accident Prevention
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Using [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".chosen-results li").forEach((li) => {
  li.classList.toggle("u-hidden", li.textContent.trim().startsWith("-"));
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */
.u-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">
    -General Discussion
  </li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">
    Accident Prevention
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Using String index *[i]*

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".chosen-results li").forEach((li) => {
  li.classList.toggle("u-hidden", li.textContent.trim()[0] === "-");
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */
.u-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">
    -General Discussion
  </li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">
    Accident Prevention
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works as well on a static html page. I want to make this work in a Chosen drop down select list, which starts collapsed until you click on it.

Comment: Than, use the above code as appropriate for that Chosen plugin (I have no direct knowledge about that one)